# Find dup records with different extensions in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a subscriptions table. Sample records:

```
  SUBS_ID    |   SUBS Name
     1       |   SC FORM 124
     2       |   SC FORM 124-R
```

I need to find both the records, as the subscription name is exactly the same but just with an extension-R.

Comment: Are you querying for all records in the table where the SUBS Name matches with or without "-R"? Or just all records with the exact SUBS Name = 'SC FORM 124' or 'SC FORM 124-R'.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. In order to help we need some details about your tables, the data and your desired output. See this article for a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: you need to compare all the records and return back? Can you provide example with more data and your expected output?

Comment: All Subscription that have the exact name but could possibly have different extensions

Comment: Ex: SC FORM 124,   SC FORM 124-R,   SC FORM 124-1-R

Comment: So, in the above example when I query the table I should get all 3 records ...the first one being the base record and the remaining 2 being the extensions

Comment: Checked my answer?

Comment: So, the approach what was baselined here was, to first find all records that have the extension -R and then find all their corresponding base records without the R

Answer (score 1):

Really bad throwaway code written straight here and untested, but...

```
with cte As (Select Name, Id
From Subs
Where Name Not Like '%-R'
)
Select cte.Id, cte.Name, M.Name
From Subs As M
Join cte
On cte.Name + '-R' = M.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use row_Number and partition by as below:

```
Select * from (
    Select *, DupeRecords = Row_number() over(partition by replace([Subs Name],'-R','') order by Subs_Id)
       from #yoursubs
   ) a Where a.DupeRecords > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your latest criteria:

> So, in the above example when I query the table I should get all 3
>   records ...the first one being the base record and the remaining 2
>   being the extensions – SQL User 17 mins ago

```
SELECT distinct
    0 as Subs_ID
    , CASE WHEN SUBS_Name like '%-%' THEN left(SUBS_Name,charindex('-',SUBS_Name)-1) ELSE SUBS_Name END AS SUB_NAME_MAIN
    , '' as Extension

FROM 
    subs

UNION

SELECT
    Subs_ID
    , CASE WHEN SUBS_Name like '%-%' THEN left(SUBS_Name,charindex('-',SUBS_Name)-1) ELSE SUBS_Name END AS SUB_NAME_MAIN
    , CASE WHEN SUBS_Name like '%-%' THEN RIGHT(SUBS_Name, LEN(SUBS_Name) - charindex('-',SUBS_Name)+1) ELSE '' END AS Extension

FROM 
    subs
```

will produce the following result.  A 'Master' row that is given an arbitray ID number of '0' and each row of that master's family and its extension.

```
Subs_ID     SUB_NAME_MAIN        Extension
----------- -------------------- --------------------
0           SC FORM 124          
1           SC FORM 124          
2           SC FORM 124          -R
```